# Match "/" Once In Awk

Tags: awk, terminal

I'm trying to use awk to pull out particular substring in a file path. Given that I have something coming into the awk command as `a/workspace/folder.fold/secondfolder/file.ext`, how do I get it to result as `folder.fold/secondfolder/file.ext`?

I was trying to do

```
| awk -F "/" '{ print $2 }'
```

but that only gives me `folder`. Any help is certain appreciated, as I'm very new to awk.

Edit: It's actually coming in as `a/workspace/folder.fold/secondfolder/file.ext`. The extra `a/` gets pulled as $1 in my attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is not the best tool for this, but you can do:

```
awk '{ sub( "/[^/]*/","")}1'
```

Comment: The whole thing (a grep from a mercurial command) is being executed in terminal, so my understanding was that I had only awk and maybe sed to work with. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If you are filtering a stream,  you can do `cut -d/ -f3-` or `sed 's@/[^/]*/@@'`.

Answer (score 1):

some of the ways to achieve desired output are

```
echo '/workspace/folder.fold/secondfolder/file.ext' | awk -F/ '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s" ,$i FS)}

echo '/workspace/folder.fold/secondfolder/file.ext' | cut -d / -f 3-
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try sed

```
sed -re 's@([^/+]/)([^/]+/)@@' temp.txt
```

Input

`a/workspace/folder.fold/secondfolder/file.ext`

Output

`folder.fold/secondfolder/file.ext`